# Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 - error after installing publisher

Tags: tridion

We have a 2011 SP1 CM server that we've recently updated with HR1 - it didn't have the Publisher installed as this was on a separate server.

This other server is being re-purposed, so I went and installed the Publisher from the 2011 SP1 CM installer.

Sadly the Publisher service won't start - I get "Error 1068 The dependency service or group failed to start."

Anyone seen this before?
Could it be caused by installing a 2011 SP1 Publisher into a 2011 SP1 HR1 CM?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The only service in the dependencies I can think of are the *Transport Service* and the *Distributed Transaction Controller*. Can you validate that that the *Transport Service* installed and running on that machine? Both of the services in turn depend on *Remote Procedure Call*. The *DTC* also uses the *Security Accounts Manager*. Double check these are all in place.

You might also want to double check you have a valid `cd_licenses.xml` file for that server, as that is required by the *Transport service*. If it is there, make sure it has a valid expiry date (or none at all) and has a server name that matches your server in it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, will do. So theres nothing fundamentally wrong with trying to install a 2011 SP1 Publisher into an existing 2011 SP1 HR1 env?

Comment: I can't think of any reason it should be an issue, but can't say I have ever tried